# What's the use of require.js when combining all scripts for deployment ?

Tags: requirejs

For deployment, it is suggested that all .js files be combined in order to reduce number of network requests. 
Require.js provides support for dynamic loading of scripts. What value does require.js bring if all .js files are combined and thus already loaded in single request.

Is it just to simplify the dev environment, by breaking code into separate files?

Answer (score 1):

You combine your application logic in one file, but you may have external libraries which will be loaded on demand: jQuery, Twitter Bootstrap, Knockout.js etc.

Comment: do you mean when I am loading external libraries through their cdn ? because otherwise I will have one file containing all .js code - application logic + external libs

Comment: Yes, I'm loading external libraries from CDN with requirejs. I also have custom CDN for own libraries used across my projects, it's more easy to update them on CDN in one place, when to rebuild all project sources for every bugfix in shared library.

Answer (score 0):

RequireJS is supposed to be used in development as much as in production. It is not mean just for file dependency management during dev time , building a single file with r.js for production is an option but not mandatory. RequireJS is not just a development tool.

> it is suggested that all .js files be combined in order to reduce
>   number of network requests

not an issue on desktop where browsers know how to load code in parallel , resulting in shorter loading times than for 1 big file.

Comment: what are the benefits of require.js if I do decide to combine all .js files?

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons to use require.js even in this scenario:

- You can declare dependencies between modules explicitly, which makes it possible to automatically detect unneeded modules so they are not included in the combined file.
- It forces you to think a bit more about the modularity of your code, which might result in cleaner code.

There are also some reasons not to use require.js:

- If your dependencies are pretty simple you may not get much benefit from require.js
- The setup to use require.js is likely to be more complicated.
- You must take special care to use almond.js instead of require.js for your deployment or you will risk getting a larger .js file than before.

Comment: "It forces you to think a bit more about the modularity of your code, which might result in cleaner code." requirejs only care about files , not what is inside it. It may look like DI but it is purely about file dependency resolution. The code itself is less modular since it depends on requirejs...

Comment: You must wrap your code in define(..) calls so you are not automatically creating globals. That is a very important difference between writing modules with require.js (or AMD) and loading javascript files directly: with modules you must think about what you want to expose and return that explicitly in an object.

Comment: there is no native way to manage file dependencies clientside. The problem is rjs modules are hard to integrate in non rjs projects, unless you introduce requirejs as a dependency. And what if another project uses another amd library ? that's in my opinion the problem with these libs and why i feel they dont promote real modularity on a pure javascript level.